# Request.uri is empty for routes to handle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, env

I'm having this weird issue, where, as far as I can tell, Request isn't set, for some reason.

None of the trace is from my app, only gems, and I can't seem to figure this out. I've tried disabling gems, including newrelic, without luck.

From what I can see here, there's nothing uncommon, that would unset the `Request.new env` call from `lib/action_dispatch/routing/redirection.rb` in `call?`

Also worth mentioning, that this is triggered on any call, on any URL I could call from my browser, leading me to believe it has nothing to do with the code, but some gems, or my setup.

**Info**

- Running Ruby 2.2.3
- Rails 4.2.4
- OS X

**Stacktrace**

```
/Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:17:in `rescue in split'
/Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:14:in `split'
/Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:72:in `parse'
/Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/common.rb:226:in `parse'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/redirection.rb:26:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/redirection.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:51:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack-attack (4.4.1) lib/rack/attack.rb:107:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:30:in `traced_call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:32:in `traced_call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:48:in `traced_call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
http_accept_language (2.0.5) lib/http_accept_language/middleware.rb:14:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rails_event_store (0.11.0) lib/rails_event_store/middleware.rb:14:in `_call'
rails_event_store (0.11.0) lib/rails_event_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
ahoy_matey (1.4.2) lib/ahoy/engine.rb:22:in `call_with_quiet_ahoy'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
request_store (1.3.1) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
/Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bundler/gems/font_assets-457dcfddc431/lib/font_assets/middleware.rb:29:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack-cors (0.4.0) lib/rack/cors.rb:80:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.16.0.318) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
puma (2.16.0) lib/puma/server.rb:557:in `handle_request'
puma (2.16.0) lib/puma/server.rb:404:in `process_client'
puma (2.16.0) lib/puma/server.rb:270:in `block in run'
puma (2.16.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:106:in `call'
puma (2.16.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:106:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: what is your code that triggers this?

Comment: Nothing. A request to `http://localhost:3000` gives me this error.